# Accessing number of quick notifications on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a clock app for the night, that is always visible, and I'm wondering if is there any way to access the number of quick notifications, like on the lockscreen(for ex.: number of missed calls, emails, messenger/viber/whatsapp messages, etc..) So I could display these icons with numbers in my app.
[image: these guys at the bottom]
<sub>(source: [softpedia-static.com](http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Windows-Phone-8-s-Lock-Screen-to-Sport-More-Notifications-2.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way for an app to access these. They are available only to the lock screen. Apps are generally isolated from the system and from other apps and are unable to access information that could have privacy concerns.